# Update Windows 7-32 bit

Tags: windows-7, updates

Windows is continually asking me to update files  KB4099633 and KB4103472.
I have updated KB4099633 eight times, KB4103472 five times, but I am still being asked to update. All other windows updates are normal, no problems.
Can anybody help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this page....https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/910339/windows-update-or-microsoft-update-repeatedly-offers-the-same-update

Answer (score 0):

This is a unusual problem. Yet, Windows 7 always had some kind of update issues.

I recommend uninstalling both updates and reinstalling them manually via the Microsoft website. Click the following links below to download your updates.

[KB4099633](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4099633)

[KB4103472](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4103472)

Chose the middle one, as it suits best for your 32-bit device. I hope this helps.